# choropleth map usind folium code is not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am trying to creat a choropleth map using folium, and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.read_csv(r'crime in SF.csv')
count = ['Count']
df4 = df3.groupby('Neighborhood')[count].sum()
df4.reset_index(inplace = True)

df4['Count'] = df4['Count'].astype(int)

data = {"Neighborhood": df4["Neighborhood"], 'Count': df4['Count']}
df5= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugs6D.png)

```
import json
sf= json.load(open('san-francisco.geojson', 'r'))
sf= r'san-francisco.json'

import folium

world_map=folium.Map([37.77, -122.42], zoom_start=12, tiles='Mapbox Bright')


threshold_scale = np.linspace(df5['Count'].min(),
                          df5['Count'].max(),
                          6, dtype= int)
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() 
threshold_scale[-1]= threshold_scale[-1] + 1

folium.Choropleth(geo_data= sf, 
             name ='choropleth', 
             data= df5,
             columns= ['Neighborhood','Count'],
             key_on='feature.properties.OBJECTID',
             color='YlOrRd',
             highlight=True,
             fill_opacity = 0.7,
             line_opacity=0.2,
             legend_name='Crime Rate in San Fancisco',
             threshold_scale=threshold_scale,
             reset=True).add_to(world_map)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(world_map)




display(world_map)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf6El.png)

it always give back an error about something in the bins( see image 2) and says something about histogram although i have not wrote any code about histograms

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the bins in your variable `threshold_scale`. You can print the content of this variable to understand the problem. You specify that you want to have bins as `int` numbers and I think that numpy stores it in a integer of 32 bits (or smaller) so the maximum number that you can use is 2147483647 and your values in `df5` are above that number. To solve your problem, you can use a `int64` instead :

```
threshold_scale = np.linspace(df5['Count'].min(),
                          df5['Count'].max(),
                          6, dtype= np.int64)
```